# Change MySQL query to Oracle

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

I have the SQL query below working on MySQL database server but the production server runs on Oracle DB instead. Would be over the moon if someone can assist with converting this query to work in Oracle DB:

```
SELECT LAS_NAME as lastName, 
       OTHER_NAMES as firstName, 
       NUBAN as accountNumber, 
       FLG as account_status, 
       CUS_EMAIL as emailAddress,  
       CUS_MOBILE as phoneNumber 
FROM " . TABLE_NAME . " 
WHERE `OTHER_NAMES` LIKE ? AND 
      (CUS_EMAIL = ? OR 
       CUS_MOBILE = ?)
```

NB: This query works fine on MySQL but when I tried on the Oracle DB, keeps returning an error.

Comment: Update the question with the error message you get!

Comment: I don't think Oracle needs the backticks round column names (`\`OTHER_NAMES\``)

Comment: It's a bad idea to develop in MySQL when the target DBMS is Oracle.

Comment: *I tried on the Oracle DB, keeps returning an error*. Aha, you probably have a good reason for not telling us *which* error? Usually Oracle tells you quite precisely what the error is. Didn't it help you? Why not? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

To my limited Oracle knowledge this is how it should look:

```
SELECT LAST_NAME as lastName, 
       OTHER_NAMES as firstName, 
       NUBAN as accountNumber, 
       FLG as account_status, 
       CUS_EMAIL as emailAddress,  
       CUS_MOBILE as phoneNumber 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE OTHER_NAMES LIKE '?%?' AND 
      (CUS_EMAIL = '?' OR 
       CUS_MOBILE = '?');
```

Remember to end PLSQL statements with a ;(semicolon) at the end.

As for the like statements, remember to use 'single quotes' since Oracle it very specific about strings.

For the table name you should not use quotations, PLSQL can be a cruel mistress if she wants to be. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are passing table_name and like as prompt below works for me

```
SELECT LAS_NAME as lastName, 
       OTHER_NAMES as firstName, 
       NUBAN as accountNumber, 
       FLG as account_status, 
       CUS_EMAIL as emailAddress,  
       CUS_MOBILE as phoneNumber 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE  OTHER_NAMES LIKE '%' AND 
      (CUS_EMAIL = '' OR 
       CUS_MOBILE = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a MYSQL expect and don't understand the symbolic value of `" . TABLE_NAME . "` so I'm just going to assume you mean a table name. In Oracle if the table is not in another schema or a remote database we just use the table name.

Likewise the backtick ` is not a valid symbol in Oracle.

```
SELECT LAS_NAME as lastName, 
       OTHER_NAMES as firstName, 
       NUBAN as accountNumber, 
       FLG as account_status, 
       CUS_EMAIL as emailAddress,  
       CUS_MOBILE as phoneNumber 
FROM your_table
WHERE OTHER_NAMES LIKE ? AND 
      (CUS_EMAIL = ? OR 
       CUS_MOBILE = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Try this steps with  appropriate according to your table names and columns name
  you will get the answer at step 3
- STEP 1:

  SELECT las_name AS lastname, 
         other_names AS firstname, 
         nuban AS accountnumber, 
         flg AS account_status, 
         cus_email AS emailaddress,
         cus_mobile AS phonenumber 
  FROM  table_name
  WHERE other_names LIKE '%?%' ;

  - STEP 2:

  SELECT las_name AS lastname, 
         other_names AS firstname, 
         nuban AS accountnumber, 
         flg AS account_status, 
         cus_email AS emailaddress,
         cus_mobile AS phonenumber 
  FROM  table_name
  WHERE other_names LIKE '%?%' 
  AND (cus_email = '?') ;

  - STEP 3:

  SELECT las_name AS lastname, 
         other_names AS firstname, 
         nuban AS accountnumber, 
         flg AS account_status, 
         cus_email AS emailaddress,
         cus_mobile AS phonenumber 
  FROM  table_name
  WHERE other_names LIKE '%?%' 
  AND (cus_email = '?'
   OR  cus_mobile = '?');